# Flutter - In autocomplete search location - The argument type 'List<String>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When I'm run autocomplete search location using firebase_google_place library and use as per document implementation that time I got below error on run time.

The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List' because 'List?' is nullable and 'List' isn't.

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
  types: widget.types,

Comment: Have you read https://dart.dev/null-safety ? Also, please share the line of code which gives the error.

Comment: Change your variable to `List<String>? _yourList;`

Answer (score 0):

Just before you do something with the List you got from firebase_google_places, check if the list you is null:

```
void main() {
  List<String>? list = getList();
  
  // check if null
  if(list != null) {
    checkList(list);
  }
}

void checkList(List<String> list) {
  print(list.first);
  print(list.last);
}

List<String>? getList() {
  return ["Test", "jdsgksa", "hsjgaiop"];
}
```